# How stop checkbox ticks from closing its div when clicking outside

Tags: jquery, html

Thanks to SO posts I'm at last able to close a div by clicking anywhere outside it.  My problem is that my div to be closed contains additional divs with checkboxes.  I want to be able to click the checkboxes without closing the div.
Does anyone know the most efficient way of doing this? I think the fiddle demonstrates the problem  http://jsfiddle.net/s72q85fm/   Any help much appreciated.

```js
$(function() {

  $("#startbutton").click(function(e) {

    if ($('#MainContainer').is(":visible")) {
      $('#MainContainer').fadeOut(200);
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#MainContainer").fadeIn(200, function() {
        $(this).focus();
      });
    }
  });

  $("#MainContainer").on('blur', function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(200);
  });
});
```

```css
#MainContainer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
}
#CheckboxContainer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Universe">
  <button id='startbutton'>Open Box</button>
  <div id="MainContainer" tabindex="-1">
    <div id="CheckboxContainer">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="myRegion" />
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="myCountry" />
      </label>
    </div>"
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use `.blur()` for this. Detect a click event outside the box, and use that to close it.

Comment: In your case, I'd have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/sxbducmv/

Comment: @Barmar, I spent hours trawling through all these posts... obviously there were things that were much related to my question but I couldn't find anything that duplicates what I've asked, given the specific method I'm using.  Would appreciate if you could be specific as to where I can find the duplicate.  I must add that in my case I wasn't able to get most of the other approaches working at all.

Comment: @ValLeNain you've given a link to something that looks exactly like the fiddle I originally attached.

Comment: sorry, forgot to save the draft :) http://jsfiddle.net/sxbducmv/1/ should be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your blur listener check for `e.relatedTarget.type` of event and don't blur if it is a checkbox and also get back the focus to `MainContainer` instead of blur if it is a checkbox (see the else block of below code)

UPDATE:

We also need to check for `null` value of `e.relatedTarget` as it will be null when click outside.

```
$("#MainContainer").on('blur', function(e) {
    if(!(e.relatedTarget!=null&&
          e.relatedTarget.type=='checkbox'))  $(this).fadeOut(200);
    else $(this).focus();
});
```

```js
$(function() {

  $("#startbutton").click(function(e) {

    if ($('#MainContainer').is(":visible")) {
      $('#MainContainer').fadeOut(200);
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#MainContainer").fadeIn(200, function() {
        $(this).focus();
      });
    }
  });

   $("#MainContainer").on('blur', function(e) {
    if(!(e.relatedTarget!=null&&e.relatedTarget.type=='checkbox'))
       $(this).fadeOut(200);
    else{$(this).focus();} 
  });

});
```

```css
#MainContainer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
}
#CheckboxContainer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Universe">
  <button id='startbutton'>Open Box</button>
  <div id="MainContainer" tabindex="-1">
    <div id="CheckboxContainer">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="myRegion" />
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="myCountry" />
      </label>
    </div>"
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check for null value when event not generated from checkbox

Check my updated code.

Comment: @Nadir Laskar this works beautifully and most importantly I've learned from your explanations.  I much prefer this approach to one that detects a click outside the box and continues to register every single click the User makes.

Comment: I am glad, it helped and yes it is a much better approach over listening for every click.